If you create a power tower of all the digits in a number, calculate that out, and repeat this process, will you always reach a single digit number?
It's helpful to understand what I'm talking about here by going through some examples. Pick an arbitrary number, for this example we'll choose 37. Creating a power tower of it's digits would look like 3^7, which is equal to 2187. Then we create another power tower, this time 2^1^8^7. When you have multiple exponents in a tower like this without any parentheses, you always start from the top of the power tower. So you'd have 2^1^8^7 = 2^1^2097152 = 2^1 = 2. And you can't create a power tower of just 1 number, so you're done. My conjecture is this: For any natural number, in a finite number of steps, you will always reach a single digit number. The astute among you might ask what happens when you have 2 zeros in a row in the number, because then you'd have 0^0, which is undefined. But for this problem, we'll define 0^0 to be the limit of x^x as x approaches zero from the right side of the number line, which is 1.
When I first thought of this problem, I thought that many sequences would just blow up to infinity. That was, until I realized the effects of 1 and 0 in this problem. Every time you reach a 0 in the number during the power tower process, it resets the value of the power tower down to that point to zero (unless it's 0^0). Whenever you reach a 1, it resets the value of the power tower down to that point to 1.
Now, there are 2 ways my conjecture could be wrong. The first way is that there is some sort of cycle of numbers that never reaches a single digit number. The second way is that there is some value that does blow up to infinity. For whatever reason, the 1s and 0s are rare enough near the beginning of the number that the value never has a chance to take the sequence down to a single digit number.
I'll admit, I haven't done much testing yet. Here are the first 20 numbers that I don't know if they reach a single digit number or not:
48, 54, 57, 65, 66, 67, 73, 78, 85, 97, 99, 224, 225, 242, 252, 253, 255, 257, 265, and 268.
When it came to the much larger numbers, I stopped using Google's calculator which only calculates numbers less than 2^1024 before it starts displaying infinity, and started using this other calculator I found: Online Big Number Calculator. Unfortunately, this calculator starts to break at around 2^2^23, which is well into the thousands of digits. I've since then found an even better calculator: Big Number Calculator (online tool) | Boxentriq. This one calculated numbers as large as 2^2^28, though it does start to take a while after 2^2^25, despite me using a pretty powerful pc. It is possible that with even higher powered pc's you could calculate 2^2^29 or higher using that calculator. I might have to write my own calculator program that takes some short cuts since we only really care about the last dozen or so digits since the 0s and 1s will be resetting things all over the place in the power towers.
I'm also interested in doing this process in other bases. In binary, it's pretty straight-forward to prove. Everything is a zero or 1, so all sequences will drop to a 0 or 1, in just 1 step. I don't know about any other bases though.
Here are the numbers that this sequence ends in 0 steps (because they're already just 1 digit):
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
Here are the numbers that end in 1 step:
22, 23, 32, any number that begins with a 1, any number that's 2nd digit is a 0 or 1, any number that's 3rd digit is 0, and any number who's first 3 digits are 221, 231, or 321. Please let me know if I missed some numbers in this one.
At just 2 steps is starts getting very complicated to find the set of all numbers that reach 1 digit, so I will just list some and probably will increase the list later:
24, 25, 27, 29, 34, 37, 39, 45-47, 53, 55, 56, 59, 63, 64, 69, 75, 76, 79, 83, 84, 87-89, 92, 222, 226, 228, 229, 232, 233, 235, 238, 239, 241, 243-249, 251, 254, and 259. Please let me know if you notice any patterns in these numbers.
Another observation I have made is that excluding the starting and ending numbers, each number in the sequence will be some power of a single number. The results of these powers must be at least 2 digits.

Powers of 2s: 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192...
Powers of 3s: 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683, 59049, 177147...
Powers of 4s: 16, 64, 256, 1024, 4096, 16384, 65536, 262144...
Powers of 5s: 25, 125, 625, 3125, 15625, 78125, 390625, 1953125...
Powers of 6s: 36, 216, 1296, 7776, 46656, 279936, 1679616...
Powers of 7s: 49, 343, 2401, 16807, 117649, 823543, 5764801...
Powers of 8s: 64, 512, 4096, 32768, 262144, 2097152, 16777216...
Powers of 9s: 81, 729, 6561, 59049, 531441, 4782969, 43046721...

We can further restrain these values by adding a constraint to the exponent if it is at least 2 digits: it must be a power of a single digit number. And if that exponent also has at least 2 digits, it also must be a power of a single digit number, and if that exponent also has at least 2 digits, it also must be a power of a single digit number, and so on and so forth.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'm adding a community wiki answer for people to contribute to so the comments under the question don't get clogged again.
The main issue with this problem is computability; many CASes have 63-bit signed exponentiation, and while some have clever tricks to push it a bit further, the sheer height of the tetration of most of these numbers makes it nigh impossible to predict, deduce, or analyze the overall behavior.
Tried to find a non-trivial counterexample but failed:
No fixed point with starting value $n\in[10,999]$ has been found.
-example of fixed point: $n=\overline{ab} \to a^b =\overline{ab1\ldots}$ or $=\overline{abD0\ldots}$ for any digit $D$.
Let alone 4-digit fixed points, period-2 cycles,...

I appreciate the community wiki. The first deduction is incorrect, because
$$6^{32}\ \not\rightarrow\ 6^9,$$
but instead
$$6^{32}=7958661109946400884391936\ \rightarrow\ 7^{9^{5^{\dots}}}.$$
For the same reason the next few fail, perhaps even all of them.

I think you have to evaluate the expression in its entirety though.

I'm not sure what your comment is supposed to mean. I'm saying that your method is incorrect.

@Servaes It makes sense to me to simplify the exponent first, but there's likely some issue with generalizing that and applying it to every number. As Lucien said, evaluating the entire expression is probably the only way to deduce any behavior.
